# Android geocoder isPresent returns false, which backend service is missing?

Tags: android, google-geocoder

I implemented a small app that uses a reverse Geocoding service and it's not working correctly on a specific device with Android 4.4.2 (rooted).
Using the geocoder.getFromLocation() always returns 0 results. Calling geocoder.isPresent() always returns false.

I run the same code on other devices with Android 4.4.4 and 4.1.2 and it works smoothly.

The problematic device was missing several Google packages which I manually installed (Google Play Services, Maps and others).

I've seen several similar questions, but haven't found yet an answer.

Can someone tell how can I find which backed service is missing on the phone?
Or some other solution? (Not Google Map API)

Below is the code I use for reverse Geocoding:

```
public void getMyLocationAddress() {
        double fixLatitude = 37.423247;
        double fixLongitude = -122.085469;
        Geocoder geocoder= new Geocoder(this, Locale.ENGLISH);

        if (geocoder.isPresent()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"geocoder.isPresent..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(fixLatitude, fixLongitude, 1);
                if(addresses != null) {
                    Address fetchedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                    StringBuilder strAddress = new StringBuilder();
                    for(int i=0; i<fetchedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                        strAddress.append(fetchedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                    }
                    tvLocationAddress.setText("I am at: " +strAddress.toString());
                }
                else
                    tvLocationAddress.setText("No location found..!");
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Could not get address..!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NOTTTTT geocoder.isPresent..! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Below is part of the build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you add     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>` and 
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>` to your manifest?